# c# - How to store ArrayList in ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, arraylist

I want to store ArrayList value in ViewState

But I am getting an error:

```
"Type 'System.Data.DataRow' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable"
```

Code:

```
  private void bindGridView()
    {
        DbConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select emp_id,emp_name,father_name,gender,designation,department,location from emp_master", DbConnection);
        OleDbDataAdapter Dbreader1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(DbCommand);
        DataSet dsemer = new DataSet();

        Dbreader1.Fill(dsemer);
        ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dsemer.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            arrList.Add(dtRow);
        }
        //Here getting an error
        ViewState["ds"] = arrList;
        EmpMasterGrid.DataSource = dsemer;
        EmpMasterGrid.DataBind();

        DbConnection.Close();
    }
```

Why I need to store ArrayList in ViewState?

By using that ViewState I will export selected gridview column to excel using the below code

```
 private void GetCheckBoxStates()
    {
        CheckBox chkCol0 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol0");
        CheckBox chkCol1 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol1");
        CheckBox chkCol2 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol2");
        CheckBox chkCol3 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol3");
        CheckBox chkCol4 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol4");
        CheckBox chkCol5 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol5");
        CheckBox chkCol6 = (CheckBox)EmpMasterGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0]
                                .FindControl("chkCol6");
        ArrayList arr;

        if (ViewState["ds"] == null)
        {
            arr = new ArrayList();
        }
        else
        {
            arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["ds"];
        }
        arr.Add(chkCol0.Checked);
        arr.Add(chkCol1.Checked);
        arr.Add(chkCol2.Checked);
        arr.Add(chkCol3.Checked);
        arr.Add(chkCol4.Checked);
        arr.Add(chkCol5.Checked);
        arr.Add(chkCol6.Checked);
        ViewState["ds"] = arr;
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
**Edited!**

Answer (score 0):

As the error sais `System.Data.DataRow` is not serializable so you can not store it in `ViewState`.

I would suggest that you make a custom class that is marked as `Serializable` that contains all the values you need and save an `ArrayList` of those objects in the `ViewState`. You would populate these objects in your `foreach` loop with data from `DataRow`.

Example:

**The data object**

```
[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    public int emp_id,
    public string emp_name,
    //other properties
}
```

**In your bindGridView method**

```
//other code
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dsemer.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    arrList.Add(new Employee
    {
        emp_id = dtRow[0],
        emp_name = dtRow[1],
        //other properties
    };
}
ViewState["ds"] = arrList;
```

Comment: How to add dataset values instead of this arraylist in the below line arr.Add(chkCol0.Checked);